# C++ remove duplicate elements in vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

Before I begin with the problem, I want to make a note. I know this has been posted and I already read posts that contain almost the same problem as mine. I apologize for that, but I did not understand exactly what to do.

So.. I have this structure

```
struct Url
{
    string host;
    string path;
    string content;
    bool visited;
};
```

In my `main()` function I am making a `vector<Url>`. So far I have filled the `vector` with the information I need.

The other questions I read here say that first i have to `sort` the `vector<Url>` in order to remove the duplicates. The only thing I want to do right now is to remove the `Url`s with equal `Url.path` value from the vector.

I will appreciate any help on that. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You wrote yourself that the vector should be sorted by data member path. So what is the problem?

Comment: Can you do the initial `sort` already, or do you need help with that too?

Comment: Just use the `set` STL instead of `vector` and specify a compare function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the problem is that it sorts it by `path`. If i have this little vector of `path` 

`path[0] = "a";
path[1] ="b";
path[2] = "c";
path[3] = "b";
path[3] = "f";`

it will sort it like `a b b c f` and i want `a b c f b`. I don`t know how to do that.

Comment: @Useless I need both the sorting and removing.

Comment: You need a function, functor or `operator<` to compare two `Url`s to see which should come first, based on their path. Once you have this, you can [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Then, making a function, functor or `operator==` to see if two `Url`s have the same path is easy. Since the linked sort documentation has an example of writing a comparison functor, which step is confusing you?

Comment: @Useless That worked, I guess I was doing something wrong. While debugging finally I understood what was the whole point of sorting and then unique removing.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First we need a function to compare Urls.

```
bool compare_url (const Url& u, const Url& v) {
    return !(u.path.compare(v.path));
}
```

Now in order to remove duplicates from the `vector`, we can make use of the functions from template library `algorithm`: `sort` and `unique`. Pass the function pointer to our compare function `compare_url` as a parameter to `sort`. In the resulting sorted vector, we can use `unique` to "remove" consecutive duplicates. Note `unique` does not really remove duplicate elements (and therefore the size of the vector remains same), rather removal is done by replacing the duplicate elements by the next element that is not a duplicate, and signaling the new size of the shortened range by returning an iterator to the element that should be considered its new *past-the-end* element [[Reference]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/). Therefore, we call `vector::erase` to remove the duplicates.

```
void remove_dup_vectors (vector <Url>& vu) {
    sort(vu.begin(), vu.end(), &compare_url);
    vector<Url>::iterator newEnd = unique(vu.begin(),vu.end(), &compare_url);
    vu.erase(newEnd, vu.end());
}
```

The complexity of the this function is  O(n lg n)(`sort`) + O(n) (`unique`).

A second and faster solution here is to use `unordered_set` container that stores unique objects. The common operations insertion, search and deletion have a constant-time complexity in the average case. This is because each key is hashed. Also note that the elements are not sorted unlike `set`.

Similar to the previous case, a comparison function is to be defined, but here the operation is `equal to` since each key is hashed.

```
bool operator==(const Url& A, const Url& B) {
    return A.path == B.path;
}
```

Further, a hash function is to be defined. Hash functions for common operations are already defined in `functional` header. We make use of that here.

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<Url> {
        size_t operator()(const Url &u) const{
            return hash<string>()(u.path);
        }
    };
}
```

With these in place, a variable `unordered_set<Url> us;` can be defined and used, with the guarantee of no duplicates and faster access.

Comment: Exactly! Now I understood what was going on! Thanks

Comment: You don't have to sort, you can just use a unordered_set (not regular set which is ordered).

Comment: @gen-y-s I've also given that solution in the comment above. The answer was for the specific question asked above.

Comment: @Erobrere i see you added unordered_set to the linked code after my comment. It is crucial to use a unordered_set which is a hash table with constant time lookup, and not set which is a BST. Also your original answer  to use a sort is wrong and should be deleted

Comment: @gen-y-s The asker has the confusion of how to sort and filter out duplicates, which is addressed in the answer since the primary goal of an answer is to clarify/provide solutions. Further, in these comments, I've given other methods namely set and unordered_set (thanks to you!) that are better. Please explain why my original answer is incorrect. I will add unordered_set to improve the answer based on your earlier comments.

Comment: @Erobrere the problem of removing duplicates is a well known and popular problem, and the answers are also well known and quite simple.  The best way to do it is using a hash table, unless there is a constraint on using additional memory. Any other answer is sub-optimal and is therefore wrong,  just like if you were asked how to sort a list and you would say "bubblesort". That's simply an unacceptable answer and would be rejected in any interview and most likely disqualify the candidate.

Comment: Agreed. If the question is right, you'll expect to get the optimal answer. If the question is asking for sub-optimal ...

Comment: Disagreed... the question was fine, it just asked if sorting was the best approach, or if there is a better solution. Secondly it's not appropriate to edit answers which are wrong and add to them a completely different answer. And finally, your explanation of using unordered_set is incomplete, as youneed to use the unordered_set to actually remove items from the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to know how to sort your structure.
You may give a less than operator or a functor that can order the Urls.
An example of the operator would be:

```
bool operator<(const Url &l, consr Url &r){
   return tie(l.path, l.host, l.content. l.visited)<tie(r.path, r.host, r.content, r.visited);
}
```

You can then sort the vector by calling `std::sort`.

Reference:

1. [Less than comparabale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable)
2. [tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: That helped, I added a `==` operator also, then sorted and then equally erased. Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev You don't need the == operator. Usually the < operator suffices. Check this: https://github.com/bashrc-real/Codearchive/blob/master/cpp/Strict_weak_ordering_and_stl.md
Also if you a find a post useful, you can upvote. :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote, I tried though. Like I said, Helpful!